# R function with separating data and finding linear regression

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, linear-regression, lm

I want to calculate the impact that height has on earnings given the gender. I divided my data into data for male and female but when I run the lm(earnings~height+education+age, data = data_female) function it gives me an error saying: Error in model.frame.default(formula = earnings ~ height + education +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'education')

Would you be able to help in either suggesting a better way to refine my model or helping to fix this particular error? Please let me know.

```
setwd("~/Google Drive/R Data")
data <- read.csv('data_ass5.csv')
height <- data$height
earnings <- data$earnings
gender <- data$sex
age <- data$age
education <- data$educ
multiple_regression <- lm(earnings~height+age+gender+education,data = data)
lm(earnings~height+age+gender+education,data = data)
summary(multiple_regression)
summary(linear_regression)
multiple_regression_redefined <- lm(earnings~age+gender+education,data = data)

# Now I wish to particularly assess the impact of gender on earnings
# therefore  trying to refine my model doing the following: 
# but the lm last line is causing an error. Would you be able to adivse on 
# if this is the correct way to refine it and/or why I am getting the error.
# I even tried putting na.rm=TRUE after the lm code, but error still. 

data_female <- subset(data,gender==0)
data_male <- subset(data,gender==1)
lm(earnings~height+education+age, data = data_female)
```

Comment: Hello SMN, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Delete all of these and similar commands: `height <- data$height`

Comment: I have edited the way in which I am asking my question --- thank you for directing me to that page. Would you be able to suggest why I am going wrong now and where?

Answer (score 0):

Per [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm) of **`lm`**, the *data* argument handles variables in formula in two ways that are NOT mutually exclusive:

> **data** 
>       an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible by `as.data.frame` to a data frame) containing the variables in the model. If not found in `data`, the variables are taken from `environment(formula)`, typically the environment from which `lm` is called.

Specifically, all your vector assignments are redundant and overlap with column names in the data frame except for *gender* and *education*:

```
height <- data$height
earnings <- data$earnings
gender <- data$sex
age <- data$age
education <- data$educ

multiple_regression <- lm(earnings~height+age+gender+education,data = data)
```

When above is run, all referenced names except for *gender* and *education* derive from the dataframe. But *gender* and *education* is pulled from the global environment for the vectors you assigned above. Had you used *sex* and *educ*, values would be pulled from the data frame like all the others.

Relatedly, your `subset` calls use the *gender* vector and not *sex* column. Fortunately, they are the exact same that no errors or undesired results occurred.

```
data_female <- subset(data,gender==0)
data_male <- subset(data,gender==1)
```

Therefore, when you subsetted your data, `lm` is pulling all values from the ***subsetted*** *data* and one value, *education*, from global environment. But remember *education* is based on the *full* data frame so maintains a larger length than the columns of subsetted data frame.

---

Altogether, simply avoid assigning the redundant vectors and use columns for full and subsetted data frames.

<s>`height <- data$height`</s>

<s>`earnings <- data$earnings`</s>

<s>`gender <- data$sex`</s>

<s>`age <- data$age`</s>

<s>`education <- data$educ`</s>

```
# REPLACE gender WITH sex AND education WITH educ (RENAME COLS IF NEEDED)
multiple_regression <- lm(earnings ~ height + age + sex + educ, data = data)

# REPLACE gender WITH sex
data_female <- subset(data, sex==0)
data_male <- subset(data, sex==1)

# REPLACE education WITH educ
lm(earnings ~ height + educ + age, data = data_female)
```